# Errors Shown when I try to open a project created with VS profesional with a VS comunity 2017

Tags: visual-studio, angular

It is an angular 2 based project.
These are the error displayed in the output after tried to build it.
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. Angular2 web app1
Warning Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Warning Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:  Angular2 web app1
Warning 2
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled. Angular2 web app1 1 Active

Comment: The project was set up to use features that are not available to you.  Google each error message for details.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled VS developer edition and open the project and it worked without problems, Looks like my problem was that I did install asp in my VS developer edition.